# VHDL Signed Values

Tags: vhdl

I have just started VHDL module in university and my lecturer isn't good a explaining things. How to I use/declare signed values in VHDL?

This is the basic code format I have been taught and I'm currently programming a 2bit subtractor. The information in other websites are quite confusing.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity TwoBitSubtractor is port(
    x,y     :in integer range 0 to 3;
    result  :out integer range 0 to 3);
end TwoBitSubtractor;

architecture gates of TwoBitSubtractor is
begin
    result<= x - y;
end gates;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `signed` type for specifying signed values. Integer can also be used to declare values in a more human readable manner, but with that you are out of bit-level definitions, which is not desired in VHDL in my opinion. For example, you are ignoring the the amount of bits used for any signal with `integer`, which can be good for a high level language, but not too useful for VHDL.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity TwoBitSubtractor is port(
    x      : in signed(2 downto 0);
    y      : in signed(2 downto 0);
    result : out signed(2 downto 0));
end TwoBitSubtractor;

architecture gates of TwoBitSubtractor is
begin
    result <= x - y;
end gates;
```

See the way they are declared within the entity port. More details on signed/unsigned, please check [here](https://www.nandland.com/vhdl/examples/example-signed-unsigned.html)

Also a working online simulation of `TwoBitSubtractor` with `testbench`, check [here](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2CSq)

Comment: I would like to add : If you have to manage signed/unsigned, do not use ieee.std_logic_arith.all and other ieee.std_logic_****.all libs. ieee.numeric_std.all can manage all operations they did in a better and proper way.